# Getting model default value from modelForm in django

Tags: python, django

I have something like this in `models.py`

```
class A(models.Model):
    filed1 = CharField('label',max_length=3,default="default_1")
```

and `forms.py`:

```
class AForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = A

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(AForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        setAttrs(self)
```

and function `setAttrs`

```
def setAttrs(object):
    for field_key,field_value in object.fields.items():
```

With last for loop i can access form fields and it works. But my question is can i get related field from model and than get its default value?

### NEW UPDATE

Related to this question. I have same classes but field is custom (CustomCharField). In that custom field I have attribute readOnly="True". Can i somehow access to this attribute from last for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop, you can access the default value using `initial` attribute of `field_value`.

```
def setAttrs(object):
    for field_key,field_value in object.fields.items():
        print field_value.initial
```

Above will print initial/default value of each field.